pkexec asks always for the password of the first user
maybe this had been already answered with a different title, but I did not find the thread.
The setup:

User test1 created on setup
User newUser1 added afterwards
User newUser1 runs "pkexec somecommand" and the system asks for the password of user test1

I checked /etc/polkit-1/ , but no configuration file exist in this structure.
Why does pkexec asks for the password of test1?
It should ask for the password of newUser1. Or do I understand something wrong?

Review your /etc/groups file to see the groups that test1 is a member of. Did you add newUser1 to all the appropriate groups?

... in particular, is newUser1 a member of the sudo group, which iirc policykit uses as a proxy for LocalAuthority

Thank you very much, newUser1 was missing the group "sudo".

Thanks to user535733 , the new user was not member of the group "sudo".
After adding the user to this group, pkexec started to ask for the password of new user.
